# testing function which compares two directories

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, listdir

I am trying to test a function that takes two input directories and compares if both have an equal number of files and return a boolean.

```
my_func(dir_1,dir_2):
     dir_1_len = os.listdir(dir1)
     dir_2_len = os.listdir(dir2)
     return dir_1 == dir_2
```

I want to test this function by mocking `listdir` and giving it a return value. I am new to pytest. Can anyone help me with it.

Comment: Hopefully this will help you find the bug that is in this function.

Comment: I mocked `listdir` and gave it a return value = `temp_list`. Then pass the path to directory and this mocked list to my function with `assert True`. The test passed.